# getting email content to DB

Tags: asp.net, email, crm

I have a website with CRM and the admin can send messages that will get to the client page and to the email

our client have email address in our server (mail-enable program)

if his user will decide to reply for the email we will loose his reply from the system.
is it possible to get the content of an email to DB?

Comment: plus, what database, what programming language?

Comment: ASP, db is access but we have CRON on the server if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sending and receiving email are very different tasks, as far as complexity goes.

to send, you just make the text of the email with to, from, subject, and send it to simple smtp server (like iis smtp). that's it.

when you receive, you have to know how to parse email, and where to file it. it's still possible, for example you can use same iis smtp server to programmaticaly receive emails:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142572%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx
you just have to make sure that all "From:" addresses you send email with are handled by that same server. Meaning you have to change MX record to point at your IIS server. I am not sure your setup allows that.